# How to use react-bootstrap in a react, typescript application

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have the below in my package.json as dependencies.

```
"dependencies": {
  "@types/react": "16.9.11",
  "@types/react-bootstrap": "^0.32.20",
  "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.33.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.11.0"
}
```

Have imported react-bootstrap in my component.tsx file.

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
```

Trying to use Button and variant as below :

```
<Button variant="primary" >Click Me</Button>
```

But I am getting the below error

> Property 'variant' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes &
>   IntrinsicClassAttributes & Readonly & Readonly<{
>   child...'.

Comment: You need to install bootstrap as well and add `bootstrap.min.css` to index.js file

Comment: Follow the Documentation:https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction